# MySQL - Using the result of a Stored Procedure in an Inner Join

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL Stored Procedure that returns multiple rows. Is there a way to use this result in an Inner Join with another table? I've tried:

```
SELECT ErrorMessage FROM ErrorMessage em 
INNER JOIN User_Language(pCompanyID, pUserID) l ON em.Language=l.LanguageID 
WHERE ErrorCode = pErrorCode 
ORDER BY l.LanguageOrder LIMIT 1;
```

In this example, User_Language is the stored procedure that returns a list of languages in order of preference. The intent is to return an error message in the user's preferred language.

Comment: I don't know that MYSQL can return and use a table.  I have played tricks returning a string (like ',English,Spanish,') and doing a join with something like:

Comment: I don't know that MYSQL can return and use a table.  I have played tricks returning a string (like ',English,Spanish,') and doing a join with something like:

JOIN ErrorMesage em ON User_Language(pCompanyID, pUserID)  LIKE CONCAT('%,',em.Language',',%')

I would need to think about how to order the results.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a viable solution.  Within the User_Language stored proc, I create a Temp table (called UserLanguages) which I can then use in the inner join.

```
CALL User_Language(pCompanyID, pUserID);
SELECT ErrorMessage INTO vErrorMessage FROM ErrorMessage em
INNER JOIN UserLanguages l ON em.Language=l.LanguageID
WHERE ErrorCode = pErrorCode
ORDER BY l.LanguageOrder LIMIT 1;
```